# How allow to select an image in html and visualize it as main while the remaining pictures stay as thumbnails?

Tags: html, dom

I have the following snippet of code in html:

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="product-images">
            <div class="product-main-img">
                <img src="img/product-thumb-13.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
            
            <div class="product-gallery">
                <img src="img/product-thumb-14.jpg" alt="">
                <img src="img/product-thumb-75.jpg" alt="">
                <img src="img/product-thumb-76.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I would like to allow users of the website to click on one of the three thumbnails (14,75 and 76) in the "product-gallery" class and allow it to be visualized as main image (like product 13), hence in bigger size, while the other 3 stay smaller.
The process should be applicable to anyone of the three images on click (typical visualization of products in an ecommerce website, where a particular image is made bigger on click and the others stay small).
I have looked online for applicable methods but cannot find the one I am looking for.

Thanks for the help, have a good day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved by adding an `onClick` event handler for all the secondary images to change the `src` attribute of the central image. I have used specific `id`s to select the images from the DOM. Then we flip the image sources.

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="product-images">
            <div class="product-main-img">
                <img id="primary-img" src="img/product-thumb-13.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
            
            <div class="product-gallery">
                <img id="secondary-img" src="img/product-thumb-14.jpg" alt="">
                <img id="secondary-img" src="img/product-thumb-75.jpg" alt="">
                <img id="secondary-img" src="img/product-thumb-76.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```js
window.onload = function(e){ 
    const secondaryImages = document.querySelectorAll("#secondary-img")
    const primaryImage = document.getElementById("primary-img")

    secondaryImages.forEach((image) => {
        image.addEventListener("click", function() {
            const backupSrc = primaryImage.src
            primaryImage.src = image.src
            image.src = backupSrc
        })
    })
}
```

EDIT: fixed code bugs (string literals)

Comment: Thanks, i've fixed it thanks to you. I have also added the onclick="window.open(this.src)" on the "product-main-img" to enlarge the main image for better fruition.